# Configuring IIS as a proxy that saves SOAP messages passing through

Tags: iis, web-services

Can IIS be configured as a proxy and save the webservice SOAP payloads that pass through it?

Ideally the messages would be saved to the filesystem to be picked up by our test tool. We're setting this up for our test environment as a means to validate the messages passing through the system.

We've got a constraint around having to use IIS as opposed to other web server technologies that might offer a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this. IIS can be configured to be a proxy by using a plugin called [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing).

IIS can then be configured to log calls passing through it by configuring [Failed Request Tracing](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to log all requests by including HTTP response codes of 2xx so that even non-failed requests are captured.